# How to send an email via outlook with .asp

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, outlook

I'm not to familiar with this but i have done similar in the past. Basically i want to have an html, or .asp page with a simple form for the user to input data. I've accomplished this in VB.net with the following:

```
 Imports Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
 Private Sub cmdFax_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)Handles cmdFax.Click

 Dim oApp As Outlook._Application
        oApp = New Outlook.Application()


        Dim oMsg As Outlook._MailItem
        oMsg = oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
        oMsg.Subject = ""
        oMsg.Body = "" & vbCr & vbCr

        If Len(txtEmail.Text) > 0 Then
            oMsg.To = Me.txtEmail.Text
        Else
            oMsg.To = "[Fax:" & Me.txtAttn.Text & " @ " & Me.txtFaxNum.Text & "]"
        End If

        Dim sSource As String = "C:\ValidPath.txt"
        Dim sDisplayName As String = "Hello.txt"
        Dim sBodyLen As String = oMsg.Body.Length
        Dim oAttachs As Outlook.Attachments = oMsg.Attachments
        Dim oAttach As Outlook.Attachment


        If Len(Me.TextBox1.Text) > 0 Then
            oAttach = oAttachs.Add(Me.TextBox1.Text)
        Else
        End If

        oAttachs.Add(Me.cboForm.SelectedValue)


        oMsg.Send()

        oApp = Nothing
        oMsg = Nothing
        oAttach = Nothing
        oAttachs = Nothing

        'MsgBox("Your Fax Has Been Sent Successfully")
        lblStatus.Text = "Fax Sent"


        'lblStatus.Text = "Ready"



    End If
End Sub
```

Is there anyway to accomplish the same thing using .asp? or is there an easier way to do this using a contact form and .asp page? I'm just trying to avoid using an external mail server and have the form send from the actual user.

Open to any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason your code won't work when called from an ASP.NET application.

Your requirements need to be better articulated, but the "norrmal" way to do things is via the [System.Net.Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.aspx) namespace instead of invoking Outlook.

If you don't want to use an external mail server, configure the built-in IIS SMTP Server to use the same account settings as Outlook.

Comment: Well I'm not sure how to call the outlook interop, it's not liking any of the code when wrapped in .aspx

Comment: Add a reference to `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` in your ASP.NET project and then you can write `Dim oApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application`